# how to convert a 3d shapefile to 2d in python

Tags: python, arcgis, qgis, arcpy

I have a large shapefile with 3d polygon that I want to switch to 2d to be able to work with the data in matlab. 
I have tried changing feature class in ArcGis, and in QGIS, but because of the size of the shapefile the computer crashes every time.

Is there any way to do this either in arcpy or python in qgis?

Comment: Have you looked at the [pyshp](https://github.com/GeospatialPython/pyshp) module?

Comment: I will check it out! I am very new to working with shapefiles and python. Thank you

Comment: When it comes to `.shp` files, the spec is found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shapefile#Shapefile_shape_format_.28.shp.29). The `pyshp` module's latest release is not the 2.0.0-dev that is on their GitHub page, you have to manually add that. But it is much faster than their `1.x.x` variants. However, there is an issue with POINT geometry, so using the `1.x.x` variants should be fine for now.

Comment: This looks like it would be more on-topic at the [gis.se] Stack Exchange but try to ask a more focused question.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to use, I prefer FME software to do that. It is super easy and work with GIS perfectly you can download a trial version from here https://www.safe.com/fme/fme-desktop/trial-download/

to do what you want:
1. open a workspace
2. add your shp file as a reader
3. add 2dforcer
4. add another shpfile as a writer to get an output.